# Under what conditions is a quotient of a topological spaces homeomorphic to the original space?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let´s say, we have a topological space $X$ and its subspace $S$. Take the quotient space $X/S$.

When can we say that $X/S$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

When can we say that, given $X$ is also Hausdorff?

Thank you.

(This question is not from any paper or textbook, it just came to my mind.)

Comment: I have only seen a quotient space in topology defined as $X/\sim$ where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. How do you define it for a subset $S$?

Comment: I doubt that there is a general rule, but there are some usual necessary conditions, a simple one is that if $X$ is Hausdorff and has no isolated points, then $S$ must be closed.

Comment: @spinosarus123 In this case $x\sim y$ if $x=y$ or if both $x,y\in S.$ Essentially, we send $S$ into a point.

Comment: @spinosarus123 $S$ is a subset such that any points from $S$ are identified in $X/S$. (Take the $X$ and "glue together" all the stuff from $S$.)

Comment: There might be a homology or cohomology condition - I’m forgetting the relationship between $H_n(X,A)$ in terms of $H_n(X/A).$

Comment: For sufficiently nice $X$ (say metric space), I believe if $S$ is an absolute retract, then $X/S$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: If $X=\mathbb R^n$ is $S$ is a convex and compact subset with non-empty interior, I believe it is not hard to prove it. Not sure about the case of non-convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n,$ especially something aberrant like the Koch snowflake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

Comment: @DanRust: That's false. The standard example is a wild arc $S$ in $X=R^3$ (say, one whose complement is not simply connected).

Comment: $X$ and $X/S$ are homeomorphic if you can find a quotient map $f : X \to X$ such that for all $u$ and $v$ in $X$ we have $f(u) = f(v) \iff u=v \textrm{ or } u,v \in S$.